# How can I clear a dynamically compiled class from memory

Tags: java

I Created a class `JavaRunner` that dynamically creates a file from string, compiles it in memory and runs it's main method (I also created a method that writes the file and compiles it on disk with similar results).

I created 2 other classes that call the runner.

The first is `TerminalRunner` which takes the class name and source as arguments and calls JavaRunner.compile, this works fine because it only runs once every time I call it.

The second class is `RunnerServlet` which starts a small java server that receives a post request compiles using JavaRunner and runs the code and returning a JSON object with the sys.out and sys.err streams.

if I post {name:"Main", code:"[Some Java code]"} I get the correct response; however if I call the same class Main with different source code I get the first result.

I traced the code and the source String is delivered correctly to the JavaCompiler.
The problem has to do with the compiled class, my guess it is somehow cached by the JVM.

This is The compile method in `JavaRunner.java`

```
public static void compile(String name, String code, int timeLimit){

    /*Creating dynamic java source code file object*/
    SimpleJavaFileObject fileObject = new DynamicJavaSourceCodeObject (name, code) ;
    JavaFileObject javaFileObjects[] = new JavaFileObject[]{fileObject} ;

    /*Instantiating the java compiler*/
    JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();

    /**
     * Retrieving the standard file manager from compiler object, which is used to provide
     * basic building block for customizing how a compiler reads and writes to files.
     *
     * The same file manager can be reopened for another compiler task.
     * Thus we reduce the overhead of scanning through file system and jar files each time
     */
    StandardJavaFileManager stdFileManager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(null, null, null);
    try {
      stdFileManager.setLocation(StandardLocation.CLASS_OUTPUT, Arrays.asList(new File("./temp")));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    /* Prepare a list of compilation units (java source code file objects) to input to compilation task*/
    Iterable<? extends JavaFileObject> compilationUnits = Arrays.asList(javaFileObjects);

    /*Prepare any compilation options to be used during compilation*/
    //In this example, we are asking the compiler to place the output files under bin folder.
    List<String> compileOptions = new ArrayList<String>();
    // compileOptions.addAll(Arrays.asList("-classpath", System.getProperty("java.class.path")));
    // Iterable<String> compilationOptionss = Arrays.asList(compileOptions);

    /*Create a diagnostic controller, which holds the compilation problems*/
    DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject> diagnostics = new DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject>();

    /*Create a compilation task from compiler by passing in the required input objects prepared above*/
    CompilationTask compilerTask = compiler.getTask(null, stdFileManager, diagnostics, compileOptions, null, compilationUnits) ;

    //Perform the compilation by calling the call method on compilerTask object.
    boolean status = compilerTask.call();

    if (!status){//If compilation error occurs
        /*Iterate through each compilation problem and print it*/
        for (Diagnostic diagnostic : diagnostics.getDiagnostics()){
            System.err.format("Error on line %d in %s", diagnostic.getLineNumber(), diagnostic);
        }
    } else {
      // ExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

      // try {
      //     Runnable r = new Runnable() {
      //         @Override
      //         public void run() {
                try {
                  Class.forName(name).getDeclaredMethod("main", new Class[] { String[].class }).invoke(null, new Object[] { null });
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                  System.err.println("Class not found: " + e);
                } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                  System.err.println("No such method: " + e);
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                  System.err.println("Illegal access: " + e);
                } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                  System.err.println("RuntimeError: "+e.getTargetException());
                }
              // }
      //     };

      //     Future<?> f = service.submit(r);

      //     f.get(timeLimit, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);     // attempt the task for timelimit default 5 seconds
      // }
      // catch (final InterruptedException e) {
      //   System.err.println("Thread Interrupted: " + e);
      // }
      // catch (final TimeoutException e) {
      //   System.err.println("TimeoutException: Your program ran for more than "+timeLimit);
      // }
      // catch (final ExecutionException e) {
      //   e.printStackTrace();
      // }
      // finally {
      //     service.shutdown();
      // }
    }

    try {
        (new File("./temp/"+name+".class")).delete();
        stdFileManager.close() ;//Close the file manager
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is the `DynaDynamicJavaSourceCodeObject`

```
class DynamicJavaSourceCodeObject extends SimpleJavaFileObject{
private String sourceCode ;

/**
 * Converts the name to an URI, as that is the format expected by JavaFileObject
 *
 *
 * @param String name given to the class file
 * @param String source the source code string
 */
 protected DynamicJavaSourceCodeObject(String name, String source) {
    super(URI.create("string:///" +name.replaceAll("\\.", "/") + Kind.SOURCE.extension), Kind.SOURCE);
    this.sourceCode = source ;
 }

 @Override
 public CharSequence getCharContent(boolean ignoreEncodingErrors)
        throws IOException {
    return sourceCode ;
 }

 public String getSourceCode() {
    return sourceCode;
 }
}
```

Any advice?

so far I set the CLASS_OUPUT to a `/temp` directory where I delete them
however once a class is defined even after I delete it it remains in memory somewhere

Is there a way to clear classes from java's memory?

I created a repo with my current progress [here](https://github.com/amrdraz/java-runner)

My workaround, if all else fails,is to generate random file names then every 10000 compilation I would restart the server or something (but it's messy)

Comment: See [Unloading classes in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/148681/unloading-classes-in-java) for some options.

Comment: You must create a class loader, load the class using that class loader, then null out all references to the class and class loader when you're done.  (Including any classes that reference the class.  Note that this means you must use a "factory" to create instances of the class.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So thanks to the suggestions by @pm-77-1 and hot-licks in the comments

I used the`SecureClassLoader` class and made it so that the compiled bytecode is loaded there

here's the full class

```
public class JavaRunner {

public static void compile(String name, String code){
  compile(name,code,5000);
}
/**
 * compiles and runs main method from code
 * @param name      Class Name
 * @param code      String to compile
 * @param timeLimit (otional) limit for code to run, default to 5 seconds
 */
public static void compile(String name, String code, int timeLimit){

    /*Creating dynamic java source code file object*/
    SimpleJavaFileObject fileObject = new DynamicJavaSourceCodeObject (name, code) ;
    JavaFileObject javaFileObjects[] = new JavaFileObject[]{fileObject} ;

    /*Instantiating the java compiler*/
    JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();

    /**
     * Retrieving the standard file manager from compiler object, which is used to provide
     * basic building block for customizing how a compiler reads and writes to files.
     *
     * The same file manager can be reopened for another compiler task.
     * Thus we reduce the overhead of scanning through file system and jar files each time
     */
    StandardJavaFileManager stdFileManager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(null, null, null);
    //uses custom file manager with defined class loader inorder to unload the compiled class when this is done
    ClassFileManager fileManager =  new ClassFileManager(stdFileManager);

    /* Prepare a list of compilation units (java source code file objects) to input to compilation task*/
    Iterable<? extends JavaFileObject> compilationUnits = Arrays.asList(javaFileObjects);

    /*Prepare any compilation options to be used during compilation*/
    //In this example, we are asking the compiler to place the output files under bin folder.
    List<String> compileOptions = new ArrayList<String>();
    // compileOptions.addAll(Arrays.asList("-classpath", System.getProperty("java.class.path")));
    // Iterable<String> compilationOptionss = Arrays.asList(compileOptions);

    /*Create a diagnostic controller, which holds the compilation problems*/
    DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject> diagnostics = new DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject>();

    /*Create a compilation task from compiler by passing in the required input objects prepared above*/
    CompilationTask compilerTask = compiler.getTask(null, fileManager, diagnostics, compileOptions, null, compilationUnits) ;

    //Perform the compilation by calling the call method on compilerTask object.
    boolean status = compilerTask.call();

    if (!status){//If compilation error occurs
        /*Iterate through each compilation problem and print it*/
        for (Diagnostic diagnostic : diagnostics.getDiagnostics()){
            System.err.format("Error on line %d in %s", diagnostic.getLineNumber(), diagnostic);
        }
    } else {
      ExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

      try {
          Runnable r = new Runnable() {
              @Override
              public void run() {
                try {
                  fileManager.getClassLoader(null).loadClass(name).getDeclaredMethod("main", new Class[] { String[].class }).invoke(null, new Object[] { null });
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                  System.err.println("Class not found: " + e);
                } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                  System.err.println("No such method: " + e);
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                  System.err.println("Illegal access: " + e);
                } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                  System.err.println("RuntimeError: "+e.getTargetException());
                }
                try {
                    fileObject.delete();
                    fileManager.close();
                    ResourceBundle.clearCache(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()); // <--useless
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
              }
          };

          Future<?> f = service.submit(r);

          f.get(timeLimit, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
      }
      catch (final InterruptedException e) {
        System.err.println("Thread Interrupted: " + e);
      }
      catch (final TimeoutException e) {
        System.err.println("TimeoutException: Your program ran for more than "+timeLimit);
      }
      catch (final ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
      finally {
          service.shutdown();
      }
    }        
}
}
```

This prepares a dynamic java source code for compilation.

```
class DynamicJavaSourceCodeObject extends SimpleJavaFileObject{
private String sourceCode ;

/**
 * Converts the name to an URI, as that is the format expected by JavaFileObject
 *
 *
 * @param String name given to the class file
 * @param String source the source code string
 */
protected DynamicJavaSourceCodeObject(String name, String source) {
    super(URI.create("string:///" +name.replaceAll("\\.", "/") + Kind.SOURCE.extension), Kind.SOURCE);
    this.sourceCode = source ;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getCharContent(boolean ignoreEncodingErrors)
        throws IOException {
    return sourceCode ;
}

public String getSourceCode() {
    return sourceCode;
}
}
```

the idea is to create a Dynamic class instead of writing to file

```
class JavaClassObject extends SimpleJavaFileObject {

/**
* Byte code created by the compiler will be stored in this
* ByteArrayOutputStream so that we can later get the
* byte array out of it
* and put it in the memory as an instance of our class.
*/
protected ByteArrayOutputStream bos =
    new ByteArrayOutputStream();

/**
* Registers the compiled class object under URI
* containing the class full name
*
* @param name
*            Full name of the compiled class
* @param kind
*            Kind of the data. It will be CLASS in our case
*/
public JavaClassObject(String name, Kind kind) {
    super(URI.create("string:///" + name.replace('.', '/')
        + kind.extension), kind);
}

/**
* Will be used by our file manager to get the byte code that
* can be put into memory to instantiate our class
*
* @return compiled byte code
*/
public byte[] getBytes() {
    return bos.toByteArray();
}

/**
* Will provide the compiler with an output stream that leads
* to our byte array. This way the compiler will write everything
* into the byte array that we will instantiate later
*/
@Override
public OutputStream openOutputStream() throws IOException {
    return bos;
}
}
```

We use this file manager so that the compiled class from source can be unloaded also not having to write to file System

```
class ClassFileManager extends ForwardingJavaFileManager<StandardJavaFileManager> {
/**
* Instance of JavaClassObject that will store the
* compiled bytecode of our class
*/
private JavaClassObject jclassObject;
/**
 * Instance of ClassLoader
 */
private SecureClassLoader classLoader;

/**
* Will initialize the manager with the specified
* standard java file manager
*
* @param standardManger
*/
public ClassFileManager(StandardJavaFileManager standardManager) {
    super(standardManager);
    this.classLoader = new SecureClassLoader() {
        @Override
        protected Class<?> findClass(String name)
            throws ClassNotFoundException {
            byte[] b = jclassObject.getBytes();
            return super.defineClass(name, jclassObject
                .getBytes(), 0, b.length);
        }
    };
}

/**
* Will be used by us to get the class loader for our
* compiled class. It creates an anonymous class
* extending the SecureClassLoader which uses the
* byte code created by the compiler and stored in
* the JavaClassObject, and returns the Class for it
*/
@Override
public ClassLoader getClassLoader(Location location) {
    return this.classLoader; 
}

public void unloadClass(Location location) {
    this.classLoader = null;
    this.jclassObject = null;
    System.gc();
}

/**
* Gives the compiler an instance of the JavaClassObject
* so that the compiler can write the byte code into it.
*/
@Override
public JavaFileObject getJavaFileForOutput(Location location,
    String className, Kind kind, FileObject sibling)
        throws IOException {
        jclassObject = new JavaClassObject(className, kind);
    return jclassObject;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the only way for a `Class<?>` object to be garbage collected, is for the associated `ClassLoader` to be garbage collected, and this only becomes eligible for collection if there are no more references to the `ClassLoader` and any of the classes loaded through this `ClassLoader`. Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344964/when-and-how-is-a-java-classloader-marked-for-garbage-collection) for more information.

Comment: Yep, it's an important point that there must be *no* classes loaded by that loader that are still referenced.  And there must be no other references to the loader, including, eg, "parent" references from another class loader.